# Is anyone getting deployment issues with Task object? New list views from 46 causing errors

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, platform-bug

When I'm trying to deploy the native Task object to another sandbox, I am getting errors:

> 1. objects/Task.object (Task.CompletedTasks) -- Error: Value too long for field: Name maximum length is:40 (line 193, column 16)
> 2. objects/Task.object (Task.DelegatedTasks) -- Error: Value too long for field: Name maximum length is:40 (line 222, column 16)
> 3. objects/Task.object (Task.RecurringTasks) -- Error: Value too long for field: Name maximum length is:40 (line 286, column 16)
> 4. objects/Task.object (Task.UnscheduledTasks) -- Error: Value too long for field: Name maximum length is:40 (line 334, column 16)

The errors are referring to Task list views that were recently as part of the Summer '19 release. Salesforce added a label to the list view metadata:

```
<label>ENCODED:{!FilterNames.Task_DelegatedTasks}</label>
```

This is over 40 characters, so the deployment using the metadata API is throwing an error. Is anyone else having the same issue able to figure out what the problem is? Also, where would be some documentation on ENCODED for ListView labels?

I was able to do a mock deployment by manually editing the label in the metadata. The deployment succeeded

Comment: I am also getting these errors and a few extra about IsRecurring not resolving to a field

Comment: Hi and welcome to all new SFSE users. If you found this question via search and are also affected, please *do not add a "me too" answer*. You're welcome to comment if you have information to add, or write an answer if you can help solve the problem.

Comment: Adding some more information here, I have tried deploying with the mdapi with ant as well as deploying in dx format with the `sfdx force:source:deploy`. I get the error regardless of deployment method

Comment: So I made the mistake of thinking these were new standard list views. They were added by Salesforce but I was able to delete these list views as a workaround. This allowed our team to successfully deploy changes. The caveat being that this doesn't remove the list views in the destination box.

Comment: Yeah, we ended up just adding `force-app/main/default/objects/Task/listViews` to our  .forceignore file. I did submit a ticket with salesforce on this. I'll post back when I get a response

Comment: And it's a bug related to summer 19 https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003csn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Programmatic, this is a bug introduced in the Summer 19 release.

Go to: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003csn